# Make the background of PlayerControlView transparent without overriding layout file?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Is it possible to change the background color of ExoPlayer's PlayerControlView to make it completely transparent, without overriding the whole layout file?

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView
    android:id="@+id/player_controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:show_timeout="0" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this works for me in media3 1.1.0

Override the exoplayer colours in your own colour resources XML

```
    <color name="exo_bottom_bar_background" tools:override="true" >#00FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="exo_black_opacity_60" tools:override="true" >#00FFFFFF</color>
```